# Clarification of statement of performance of collection's binary search from javadoc

Tags: java, algorithm, list, collections, complexity-theory

I am confused on the performance analysis of `binarySearch` from the [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List,%20T%29)

It says:

> If the specified list does not implement the RandomAccess interface
>   and is large, this method will do an iterator-based binary search that
>   performs O(n) link traversals and O(log n) element comparisons.

I am not sure how to interpret this `O(n)` + `O(log n)`.

I mean isn't it worse than simply traversing the linked-list and compare? We still get only `O(n)`.

So what does this statement mean about performance? As phrased, I can not understand the difference from a plain linear search in the linked list.

What am I missunderstanding here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all you must understand that without `RandomAccess` interface the `binarySearch` cannot simply access, well, random element from the list, but instead it has to use an iterator. That introduces `O(n)` cost. When the collection implements `RandomAccess`, cost of each element access is `O(1)` and can be ignored as far as asymptotic complexity is concerned.

Because `O(n)` is greater than `O(log n)` it will always take precedence over `O(log n)` and dominate the complexity. In this case `binarySearch` has the same complexity as simple linear search. **So what is the advantage?**

Linear search performs `O(n)` comparisons, as opposed to `O(log n)` with `binarySearch` without random access. This is especially important when the constant before `O(logn)` is high. In plain English: *when single comparison has a very high cost compared to advancing iterator*. This might be quite common scenario, so limiting the number of comparisons is beneficial. Profit!

Comment: The key here is that the total run-time isn't really `O(n)+O(log n)` since the two Big-O s are denoting different operations. It's really `O(n)*(time to traverse a link) + O(log n)*(time to compare two elements)`. So it's important to make this distinction.

Comment: @tskuzzy: right, but technically the time is `O(n)` for sufficiently big `n`, no matter how big `time to compare two elements` is compared to `time to traverse a link`. The advantage over linear search is visible for slow comparisons.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz:Doesn't it matter that for traversal we only update a pointer?I.e. `constant operation`?

Comment: @user384706: yes, advancing the iterator once is `O(1)`, but this must be done several (hence `O(n)`) times to find the matching element.

Answer (score 2):

Binary search is not suited for linked lists. The algorithm is supposed to benefit from a **sorted collection with random access** (like a plain array), where it can quickly jump from one element to another, splitting the remaining search space in two on each iteration (hence the `O(log N)` time complexity).

For a linked list, there is a modified version which iterates through all elements (and needs to go through `2n` elements in the worst case), but instead of comparing every element, it "probes" the list at specified positions only (hence doing a lower number of **comparisons** compared to a linear search).

Since comparisons are usually slightly more costly compared to plain pointer iterating, total time should be lower. That is why the `log N` part is emphasized separately.